# How can I save the panel arrangement in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I edit a Word document, I like to put the navigation panel at the right and the style panel at the left. But when I close Word and re-open it, the panels are not there, and I have to re-open and re-position them. Is there a way to save the locations of the panels, so that they remain after re-opening Word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration within Word. However the following Macro can do the trick:

```
Sub AutoNew()
    With Application
        .TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True
        .CommandBars("Styles").Position = msoBarLeft
    End With
    ActiveWindow.DocumentMap = True
End Sub
```

Go to View > Macros > New Macro and Create two macros named "AutoNew" and "AutoOpen" and edit in the Above code.

Comment: Works great, thanks!